# How to remove the parentheses from the category widget

Tags: categories, widgets

In the default category widget, when you check the "show posts count" checkbox, the number of posts appear surrounded by parentheses, how to remove them.

Comment: Personally, I would create a custom Widget that loads the categories from the database and echoing them in whatever fashion you like with custom styling and tags. For this you will need [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) that returns the categories in an associative array and a slightly altered version of [this function](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-count-by-category#post-793609) to get the post count in each category. This might be an overkill for such a small change though.

Comment: I agree, the best way would be to create a custom widget, but i found a light solution to do this specific job, I posted it below :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this code to your functions.php file and it will remove the parentheses and surround the post count with a span with a class to easily style it.

```
function categories_postcount_filter ($variable) {
   $variable = str_replace('(', '<span class="post_count"> ', $variable);
   $variable = str_replace(')', ' </span>', $variable);
   return $variable;
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories','categories_postcount_filter');
```

++Bonus
In the archive widget, if you checked "Show posts count" checkbox you'll see the same parentheses around posts count, here's another filter to remove them and add a class to easily style theme.

```
function archive_postcount_filter ($variable) {
   $variable = str_replace('(', ' ', $variable);
   $variable = str_replace(')', ' ', $variable);
   return $variable;
}
add_filter('get_archives_link', 'archive_postcount_filter');
```

Comment: Good stuff. A bit of indentation inside the function would help.

Comment: After 6 years these two examples still work!

Comment: Would this work if the title has a parenthesis in it?